# Gradle not able to access system environmental properties

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have this script in build.gradle and i am unable to access tomcat home from system environmental variables. (FYI - null value) I verified i have environmental variable as TOMCAT_HOME = "C:\tomcatC:\apache-tomcat-8.0.21"

Any ideas what i might be doing wrong ?

```
build.mustRunAfter clean

task deploy(dependsOn: ['clean', 'build', 'deployWar']) << {
    println '*********************'
    println 'hcadmin.war installed'
    println '*********************'
}

task deployWar(type: Copy) {
    from war
    into System.getProperty("TOMCAT_HOME") + "//webapps"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Groovy way `System.env.'TOMCAT_HOME'`

Answer (score 2):

You're basically mixing up java system properties with environment variables:

To get environment variables:

```
System.getenv()["TOMCAT_HOME"] // Java-style
System.env.'TOMCAT_HOME' // Groovy-style
```

To get java system properties variables (eg with 'java.home' property):

```
System.getProperty("java.home") // Java-style
System.getProperties()["java.home"] // Java-style
System.properties.'java.home' // Groovy-style
```